# How to use concat in puppet for combining two files into same file?

Tags: puppet

```
define nagios::iconf( $host_name='', $ip='', $short_alias='',$service_name='',$remote_host_name='',$port=''){
$reconfigure = "/usr/local/nagios/etc/import/${host_name}.cfg"

   concat{$reconfigure:
      owner => nagios,
      group => nagios,
      mode  => 755
   }

   concat::fragment{"hosttemplate":
      target => $reconfigure,
      source => template('nagios/host.erb'),
      order  => 01,
   }

   concat::fragment{"servicetemplate":
      target => $reconfigure,
      ensure  => template("nagios/${service_name}.erb"),
      order   => 15
   }
}
include nagios
```

When I declare in site.pp

```
node "blahblahhostname"{
nagios::iconf{'name1':
  host_name       => 'localhost'
  remote_host_name => 'blahblah1',
  ip      => '32.232.434.323',
  port    => '111',
  short_alias     => 'random',
  service_name    => 'servicename1'
}

nagios::iconf{'name2':
  host_name       => 'localhost'
  remote_host_name => 'blahblah1',
  ip      => '32.232.434.323',
  port    => '111',
  short_alias     => 'random',
  service_name    => 'servicename2'
}
include nagios
}
```

I get duplicate declaration error. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: can you post the exact error that you get ?

Comment: Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate declaration: Concat[/usr/local/nagios/etc/import/localhost.cfg] is already declared in file /etc/puppet/modules/nagios/manifests/iconf.pp at line 9; cannot redeclare on node

Comment: Why are you declaring `nagios::iconf{''` twice? Are there two different `host_name` given in these two cases ? `host_name` decides the name of the `concat::fragments` and that may cause the problem.

Comment: there are two different servicenames.. everything else is the same.

Comment: I have added an answer to the problem. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that

```
concat{"/usr/local/nagios/etc/import/localhost.cfg"
  owner => nagios,
  group => nagios,
  mode  => 755
}
```

is defined twice because of the `host_name`. When you are calling the `define` type in your manifest it is causing the duplicate warnings.

You have to define that just once, outside of the `define` type. May be in a class or in the `manifests` itself. Something like:

```
concat{"/usr/local/nagios/etc/import/localhost.cfg"
.....
.....
```

And then, rest of the code, i.e. `concat::fragments` can go inside the `define` type.

```
define nagios::iconf( $host_name='', $ip='',     $short_alias='',$service_name='',$remote_host_name='',$port=''){
$reconfigure = "/usr/local/nagios/etc/import/${host_name}.cfg"
   concat::fragment{"hosttemplate":
      target => $reconfigure,
      source => template('nagios/host.erb'),
      order  => 01,
   }

   concat::fragment{"servicetemplate":
      target => $reconfigure,
      ensure  => template("nagios/${service_name}.erb"),
      order   => 15
   }
}
```

Comment: You are right. I declared it once outside the define type. In a class and it worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I'm not sure exactly what your are doing and if your `concat::fragment` definition will work either, but the duplicate declaration error is a result of declaring the `nagios::iconf` twice without having a unique name for these defines. You use empty strings `''` twice.

**Edit**:

if `concat::fragment` is a `define`, then `concat::fragment{"hosttemplate":` and `concat::fragment{"servicetemplate":` could be the cause of your problem.

When declaring `nagios::iconf` twice, puppet tries to declare these fragments twice. **Their name is not unique**. Try `concat::fragment{"hosttemplate $name":` and `concat::fragment{"servicetemplate $name":`

The `concat{$reconfigure:` is a `define`, too?! Try `concat{"$reconfigure $name":`.

Comment: I deleted info from empty strings.

Comment: I wasn't sure about that, as you could use empty parameters for nagios::iconf (except the name of the define, of cause)